# haproxy statistics page crashes continues

Tags: connection, statistics, reset, haproxy, was

I'm using haproxy for load balance, it works very happily.

I setup a statistics page, this page return "the connection was reset" while I refresh it sometimes.

```
listen status 0.0.0.0:8080

stats enable

stats refresh 5s

stats uri /admin
```

Is this a bug or there's some configurition problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first a "crash" would mean the process dies which is not the case. What is happening here (but you should have warnings when you start the process) is that the stats page is defined in a TCP listener instead of an HTTP one. So you need to add :

```
mode http
```

for it to work.
Also you should get other warnings about timeouts etc... Please fix warnings before asking for help, as generally they report the cause of the problem you're facing.

Comment: thank you for your answer. My Haproxy version is 1.4.23, but I didnot get a warning when start it. I changed the configure to the following:
    listen status 0.0.0.0:1082 
    #log global

    mode http

    contimeout 15s 

    clitimeout 15s 

    srvtimeout 15s

    stats enable

    stats refresh 5s

    stats uri /admin   

addtional, this is the default section in my config file:

Comment: the problem still exist. And I didnot get a warning about timeouts.

Comment: ah indeed you had a default section with all these settings, explaining why you did not have the warnings. The issue however is caused by "option nolinger" which is made exactly to close with a reset. You should never use it unless you exactly know why !

Comment: thank you! when I remove "option nolinger" from the settings,it works.

Answer (score 0):

IN addition, this is the defaults section in my config file(if it can help):

```
defaults  

log     global

mode    http  

option  httplog 

option  dontlognull
option  nolinger

option  redispatch  

retries 3

maxconn 50000 

contimeout 15s 

clitimeout 15s 

srvtimeout 15s
```